# can't access MBR, GRUB2, freshly installed Ubuntu remains "hidden* (dualboot)

Tags: grub2, mbr

-win 10 laptop

-created 160gb partition for ubuntu

-installed ubuntu 16.04 on that partition

-system reboots after installation

-win 10 boots up

-can't find my freshly installed ubuntu.

How can i access MBR or GRUB2 menu?
I have that UEFI thing. i think that's necessary to know.

Comment: If you have UEFI, MBR is not used for booting. Unless you accidentally installed Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode. Then you have to go into UEFI & turn off UEFI and/or turn on BIOS/CSM/Legacy boot mode or whatever your system calls it. Best to have Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. If Ubuntu in UEFI mode you should be able to use one time boot key, often f10 or f12 to choose to boot Ubuntu. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: http://paste2.org/JG0Ja7Ew  here's the link to my boot info. thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to boot Ubuntu installer in UEFI mode and not use BIOS/CSM mode. But Boot-Repair's is suggestiong correct re-install of grub-efi-amd64 for UEFI boot. Run that. But you originally installed grub to a partition which almost never is correct. You always install grub to a drive like sda, not sda4. With UEFI then it installs correctly to add boot files into /EFI/Boot on ESP - efi system partition. I think original install was a BIOS boot, but without grub in gpt's protective MBR, it would never boot.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for a way to browse your partitions from within Windows, Windows can't read EXT partitions by default - but there's an application that enables viewing of the partitions. See:

https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows

In case that you meant that you can't boot into Ubuntu - maybe you've done something wrong in the installation - where did you install the bootloader when asked? It should be on the root of the root of the hard drive, AFAIR.

Comment: You totally missed the question here. Please read oldfred's comment which is spot on. Please learn about UEFI because the information you provided may apply to old hardware but NOT to UEFI enabled newer ones.